# Как организовать гит?

Tags: git

Как организовать git репозиторий? Файлы сайта, куда смотрят хосты - это тоже должен быть репозиторий?

Comment: Используйте gilab.com / github.com / bitbucket.com (по вкусу).

А вот что такое "смтрящие хосты" - я не знаю.

Comment: Лучше использовать bitbucket.com, потому что на github.com создание закрытых проектов нужно оплачивать, а на bitbucket можно пользоваться бесплатно, но с ограничением в количестве разработчиков

Comment: ну на веб сервере в файлах хоста указывается путь, откуда брать файлы для обработки веб-сервером. Вот это место, где хранятся эти файлы - это ж продакшн или как? Надо делать чистый клон этого репозитория?